# Flutter SnackBar or Toast show only after each Hot Reload

Tags: flutter

when i use this method to resolve

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build problem

issue, `SnackBar`, `EdgeAlert`, `Toast` don't show on multiple click on `FloatingActionButton` but, after each **Hot Reload**, theme appear on screen,

```
_onWidgetDidBuild(Function callback) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      callback();
    });
}
```

for example:

```
body: Builder(
    builder: (scaffoldContext) => Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Text('aaa'),
          ),
          BindingWidget<_HomePageViewModel>(
              bindings: <Binding>[
                Binding('registerStatus', bindableBase,
                    _HomePageViewModel.registerStatusProperty,
                    bindingDirection: BindingDirection.TwoWay,
                    valueConverter: _NumberValueConverter())
              ],
              builder: (bc) {
                _onWidgetDidBuild(() {
                  var  registerStatus =
                      BindingWidget.of<_HomePageViewModel>(bc)
                          .getValue('registerStatus') as String;

                  print('2)  $registerStatus');

                  switch(int.parse(registerStatus)){
                    case 1:
                      EdgeAlert.show(context, title: 'Title', description: 'Description', gravity: EdgeAlert.TOP);

                      /*
                       Scaffold.of(scaffoldContext).showSnackBar(
                           SnackBar(
                              content: Text('dddddd'),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                           ),
                      );*/

                      /* Toast */
                      break;
                  }
                });
                return Container();
              }),
        ])),
```

how can i resolve this problem for this implementation my code?

thanks in advance

Comment: cannot you use `Future(computation)` instead of that `WidgetsBinding::addPostFrameCallback`?

Comment: @pskink i'm not sure, how can i use that instead

Comment: by using [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.html) `Future` constructor

Comment: @pskink could you take a sample how can i do that? i can't

Comment: what is your code then? what is unclear in `Future` constructor?

Comment: @pskink `Future(() {
                        print('aaaa');
                      });`

Comment: good, now instead of `print('aaaa');` show your `Toast`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194473/discussion-between-doldurma-and-pskink).